# Image size validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

is it possible to validate file image size with jquery class orjavascript ?

Can i do that ? I made some research but did not reach anything

Thank you

Comment: Validate..? When is an image size invalid? File size of dimension size?

Comment: size of image and its type : jpg,png etc.

Comment: Joseph i want size in terms of kbs. I dont need heigh and width

Comment: That are two separate questions. For the type: There is no reliable cross-browser method for it. As for file size, see the linked duplicate. EDIT: File size, not without making another XHR request to read the resource. It should be fetched from the cache though.

Comment: you should definitively edit the question so it is easier to understand what you actually asking. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check image file being uploaded on client side, check HTML5 File API. Here are some samples at:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

You can get file size, find it's type and access binary content.

I was using File API to read EXIF headers from image without uploading image to server.

Here is a source code:

https://gist.github.com/980275/85da4a96a3bb23bae97c3eb7ca777acdea7ed791

Comment: Getting file size is plain HTML5 (for example PlUpload uses it to show file size while uploading) and there is a JavaScript library which parses EXIF from file binary data (it looks scary, but works :-) )

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input type="file" id="loadfile" />
<input type="button" value="find size" onclick="Size()" />
```

Script:

```
 function Size() {
        if ( $.browser.msie ) {
           var a = document.getElementById('loadfile').value;
               $('#myImage').attr('src',a);
               var imgbytes = document.getElementById('myImage').fileSize;
               var imgkbytes = Math.round(parseInt(imgbytes)/1024);
               alert(imgkbytes+' KB');
        }else {
               var fileInput = $("#loadfile")[0];
               var imgbytes = fileInput.files[0].fileSize; // Size returned in bytes.
               var imgkbytes = Math.round(parseInt(imgbytes)/1024);
                       alert(imgkbytes+' KB');
         }
    }
```