# Jquery validation for Image size

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have to validate an image upload field using jquery. **Is there any way I can limit the size of the image to a maximum of 5 MB??**

My working image validator method is as follows:
`jQuery.validator.addMethod("imagesonly", function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /([^\s]+(?=\.(jpg|gif|png))\.\2)/gm.test(value);
    }, "Please enter valid image.");`

I need to add code in this so as to restrict the image size to a maximum of 5 MB.

Comment: Take a look into this: http://adamsanderson.github.io/jQuery-File-Validator/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10427219/1283215

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
var ext = $('#my_file_field').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
if($.inArray(ext, ['gif','png','jpg','jpeg']) == -1) {
alert('invalid extension!');
}
```